# expand and duplicates

Tags: duplicates, stata, reshape, expand

I have a dataset as follows.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 id str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3)
"pat"  "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
"ann"  "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"mary" "ace"      ""    ""   
"john" "ace"      ""    ""   
end
```

I want to create a separate row for each person for each drug they have. `reshape` definitely isn't what I want here: I've been experimenting with `expand` and think this is the solution.... , bar a few little things that I can't get right. I'm thinking I need to `expand` and then remove duplicates.

Step 1:

Here's the code I used to get what I want, and it works fine, except for pat: his third drug isn't copying into his third row.

```
expand 3
by id, sort: generate drug = cond(_n == 1,drug1, drug2, drug3)

* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 id str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3) str8 drug
"ann"  "thiazide" "ace" ""    "thiazide"
"ann"  "thiazide" "ace" ""    "ace"     
"ann"  "thiazide" "ace" ""    "ace"     
"john" "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"john" "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john" "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary" "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"mary" "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary" "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"pat"  "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "thiazide"
"pat"  "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "BB"      
"pat"  "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "BB"      
end
```

If anyone could instruct me on how to fix this that would be brilliant.

Step 2:
For step two (imagine that pat's rows are correct for this), I want to remove duplicates so that I am left only with the correct number of rows for each person according to their distinct number of drugs. For example, none of pat's rows should be duplicates, so I want to keep all his rows. but ann has a duplicate row that I need to remove.

This is what I have used:

```
 bys id drug: gen dup2=cond(_N==1,0,_n)
drop if dup2>1
```

This is ok, but I am left with extra rows for mary and john. I deal with these using:

```
drop if drug==""
```

Is this the most efficient/least error prone approach?

**Amendment**
It turns out the my toy dataset was too simplistic to reflect my real data. My actual data are already long, so this is why `reshape` won't work here. I am very happy to be corrected, but I think `expand` might be the way to go. Except, now, when I try to `expand` on more complex data I can not figure out how to make the loop make the dataset I need (essentially, one observation per person per drug). Here is an example of what I have:

```
clear
input str4 id int day str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3)
"ann"   14 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann"   70 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann"    1 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"ann"   35 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann "  30 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john"   1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  30 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john" 150 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  60 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  60 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john"  30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"   1 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"mary"  30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary"   1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary" 115 "thiazide" ""    ""   
"mary"  60 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary"  90 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary" 120 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"   30 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
"pat"    1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"   30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"    1 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
end
```

After using:

```
expand 3
```

Here is an example of what I want, but am unsure of how to write the code to get this. I have tried using variations of Nick Cox's loop below; but am not getting it right.

```
clear
input str4 id int day str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3) str8 drug
"ann"    1 "CCB"      ""    ""    "CCB"     
"ann"    1 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"ann"    1 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"ann"   14 "thiazide" "ace" ""    "thiazide"
"ann"   14 "thiazide" "ace" ""    "ace"     
"ann"   14 "thiazide" "ace" ""    ""        
"ann"   35 "thiazide" "ace" ""    "thiazide"
"ann"   35 "thiazide" "ace" ""    "ace"     
"ann"   35 "thiazide" "ace" ""    ""        
"ann"   70 "thiazide" "ace" ""    "thiazide"
"ann"   70 "thiazide" "ace" ""    "ace"     
"ann"   70 "thiazide" "ace" ""    ""        
"ann "  30 "CCB"      ""    ""    "CCB"     
"ann "  30 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"ann "  30 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"   1 "CCB"      ""    ""    "CCB"     
"john"   1 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"   1 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"   1 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"john"   1 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"   1 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  30 "CCB"      ""    ""    "CCB"     
"john"  30 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  30 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  30 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"john"  30 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  30 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  60 "CCB"      ""    ""    "CCB"     
"john"  60 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  60 "CCB"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  60 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"john"  60 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john"  60 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john" 150 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"john" 150 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"john" 150 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"   1 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"mary"   1 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"   1 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"  30 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"mary"  30 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"  30 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"  60 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"mary"  60 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"  60 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"  90 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"mary"  90 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary"  90 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary" 115 "thiazide" ""    ""    "thiazide"
"mary" 115 "thiazide" ""    ""    ""        
"mary" 115 "thiazide" ""    ""    ""        
"mary" 120 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"mary" 120 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"mary" 120 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"pat"    1 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"pat"    1 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"pat"    1 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"pat"    1 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "thiazide"
"pat"    1 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "BB"      
"pat"    1 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "CCB"     
"pat"   30 "ace"      ""    ""    "ace"     
"pat"   30 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"pat"   30 "ace"      ""    ""    ""        
"pat"   30 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "thiazide"
"pat"   30 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "BB"      
"pat"   30 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB" "CCB"     
end
```

At this point I can remove the observations with missing values, and clean up the dataset to get the following:

```
drop if missing(drug)
drop drug?



clear
input str4 id int day str8 drug
"ann"    1 "CCB"     
"ann"   14 "thiazide"
"ann"   14 "ace"     
"ann"   35 "thiazide"
"ann"   35 "ace"     
"ann"   70 "thiazide"
"ann"   70 "ace"     
"ann "  30 "CCB"     
"john"   1 "CCB"     
"john"   1 "ace"     
"john"  30 "CCB"     
"john"  30 "ace"     
"john"  60 "CCB"     
"john"  60 "ace"     
"john" 150 "ace"     
"mary"   1 "ace"     
"mary"  30 "ace"     
"mary"  60 "ace"     
"mary"  90 "ace"     
"mary" 115 "thiazide"
"mary" 120 "ace"     
"pat"    1 "ace"     
"pat"    1 "thiazide"
"pat"    1 "BB"      
"pat"    1 "CCB"     
"pat"   30 "ace"     
"pat"   30 "thiazide"
"pat"   30 "BB"      
"pat"   30 "CCB"     
end
```

Comment: Thanks for using `dataex` (SSC) but note that the mark-ups like `[CODE]` do not apply here, just on Statalist. The option `elsewhere` deals with this, or you can just edit them out. Talk of rows is just spreadsheet-speak; Stata calls them observations.

Comment: I think you're misreading how `cond()` works with 4 arguments. It's not equivalent to `cond(_n == 1, drug1, cond(_n == 2, drug2, drug3))` which is what you want. Using `cond()` is not a good route because it's hard to generalise to an arbitrary number of drugs.

Comment: thanks for pointers on dataex... stay tuned for an improved next question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am mystified at the dismissal of `reshape` without argument or evidence. `reshape` gets you there directly except for one line to clean out missings.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 id str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3)
"pat"  "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
"ann"  "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"mary" "ace"      ""    ""   
"john" "ace"      ""    ""   
end

reshape long drug, i(id) j(seq) 
drop if missing(drug) 
list, sepby(id) 

     +-----------------------+
     |   id   seq       drug |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |  ann     1   thiazide |
  2. |  ann     2        ace |
     |-----------------------|
  3. | john     1        ace |
     |-----------------------|
  4. | mary     1        ace |
     |-----------------------|
  5. |  pat     1   thiazide |
  6. |  pat     2         BB |
  7. |  pat     3        CCB |
     +-----------------------+
```

EDIT:

Your idea of starting with `expand` can be made to work quite easily. Underneath the hood `reshape` is doing something similar.

```
clear
input str4 id str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3)
"pat"  "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
"ann"  "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"mary" "ace"      ""    ""   
"john" "ace"      ""    ""   
end
expand 3 
sort id 
gen drug = "" 
quietly forval j = 1/3 { 
     by id: replace drug = drug`j' if _n == `j' 
} 
drop if missing(drug) 
drop drug? 
list, sepby(id)
```

EDIT 2

The extra complications are just that, complications, and don't imply a different approach. You need greater faith and to understand that `reshape` is more versatile than you think it is! See e.g. [the FAQ here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/problems-with-reshape/) as well as the help and manual entry.

Trivially, I am going to assume that `"Ann "` is just a typo for `"Ann"`. Then what we have is not just different days for the same people but also somehow duplicates for some people and days. All that means is to spell out the identifiers more fully; in fact we need one extra variable. The principle that sometimes a new identifier variable is needed to spell out a tacit order, even if arbitrarily, is discussed in the FAQ cited. The idea that "long long" layouts are possible is also a standard notion.

```
clear
input str4 id int day str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3)
"ann"   14 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann"   70 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann"    1 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"ann"   35 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann "  30 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john"   1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  30 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john" 150 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  60 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  60 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john"  30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"   1 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"mary"  30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary"   1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary" 115 "thiazide" ""    ""   
"mary"  60 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary"  90 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary" 120 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"   30 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
"pat"    1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"   30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"    1 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
end

replace id = trim(id) 
bysort id day : gen SEQ = _n 
reshape long drug, i(id day SEQ) j(seq) 
drop if missing(drug) 
list, sepby(id) 

    +-----------------------------------+
     |   id   day   SEQ   seq       drug |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. |  ann     1     1     1        CCB |
  2. |  ann    14     1     1   thiazide |
  3. |  ann    14     1     2        ace |
  4. |  ann    30     1     1        CCB |
  5. |  ann    35     1     1   thiazide |
  6. |  ann    35     1     2        ace |
  7. |  ann    70     1     1   thiazide |
  8. |  ann    70     1     2        ace |
     |-----------------------------------|
  9. | john     1     1     1        ace |
 10. | john     1     2     1        CCB |
 11. | john    30     1     1        ace |
 12. | john    30     2     1        CCB |
 13. | john    60     1     1        ace |
 14. | john    60     2     1        CCB |
 15. | john   150     1     1        ace |
     |-----------------------------------|
 16. | mary     1     1     1        ace |
 17. | mary    30     1     1        ace |
 18. | mary    60     1     1        ace |
 19. | mary    90     1     1        ace |
 20. | mary   115     1     1   thiazide |
 21. | mary   120     1     1        ace |
     |-----------------------------------|
 22. |  pat     1     1     1        ace |
 23. |  pat     1     2     1   thiazide |
 24. |  pat     1     2     2         BB |
 25. |  pat     1     2     3        CCB |
 26. |  pat    30     1     1        ace |
 27. |  pat    30     2     1   thiazide |
 28. |  pat    30     2     2         BB |
 29. |  pat    30     2     3        CCB |
     +-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Perhaps I was mistaken to disregard reshape. Thanks for pointing out that it would be a good idea to use. And also for demonstrating how to get the expand idea to work. WIll try both in my proper data and see which is quickest.

Comment: Why the "perhaps"? Without even a single reason against `reshape`, there is no case to answer. Speed isn't just a matter of execution time; time taken to write the code has to be factored in.  I am fairly experienced with `reshape` and (or but) I'd never want to use a method that entailed writing more code.

Comment: Hi again Nick, really sorry to do this, but I wonder if you could help me a little more please? The toy data I included in my question were too simplistic it turns out. I have made new toy datasets and included as an amendment above, I would be hugely appreciative of any help at all you could give me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my effort at more complex data - seems to work ok, but happy to be corrected. Or if there is another better way of doing this, please do post!

**Toy data here**

```
clear
input str4 id int day str8 drug1 str3(drug2 drug3)
"pat"    1 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
"pat"    1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"   30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"pat"   30 "thiazide" "BB"  "CCB"
"ann"    1 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"ann"   14 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann "  30 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"ann"   35 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"ann"   70 "thiazide" "ace" ""   
"mary"   1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary"  30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary"  60 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary"  90 "ace"      ""    ""   
"mary" 115 "thiazide" ""    ""   
"mary" 120 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john" 150 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"   1 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john"   1 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  30 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john"  30 "ace"      ""    ""   
"john"  60 "CCB"      ""    ""   
"john"  60 "ace"      ""    ""   
end
```

**code here:**

```
expand 3                            
gen drug=""
sort id day
egen group=group(id day drug1)      
bys id group: gen count=_n

 forval j = 1/3 { 
       bys id group: replace drug = drug`j' if count == `j' 
       }


drop if missing(drug)
drop drug? count group
```

NJC simplification:

```
expand 3                            
gen drug = ""

forval j = 1/3 { 
      by id day drug1: replace drug = drug`j' if _n == `j' 
}

drop if missing(drug)
drop drug?
```

Comment: You can cut down the number of variables as `group` and `count` can be revised out of the code. I'll edit your answer because it's hard to put that in a comment. You're free to edit it in turn. But -- more crucially -- there's a tacit assumption here that `drug1 drug2 drug3` are well behaved relative to each other. In other words, your code is very tailored to your example and still lacks the generality (and extra checks) that is given by `reshape`.

Comment: but is there a way to use reshape when my data are already long? besides making wide and then making long again... which seems to go against the principle of using less code?

Comment: I've believe I already answered your question on `reshape` in my EDIT 2 and/or the FAQ I wrote. `long` and `wide` are not set in stone. Informally, there can be long long and wide wide shapes for many datasets, and yet others; it's just that the syntax will be `wide` or `long` only and that the syntax must make sense to Stata in terms of the current dataset.

Comment: thank you for the direction to the FAQ and the demonstration in your edit. need to learn more about reshape evidently!